# Another Matchstick riddle(not puzzle)

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, matches

Here are the rules in order to manipulate the matchsticks:

1. You are required to move exactly 3 matchsticks.
2. You may rotate any whole symbol(circled in blue)or number as many times as required.
3. Most importantly, this is a riddle, not a puzzle! Solve it by arranging the matchsticks to look like the answer to the riddle. [image]

The riddle:

> Born in during Zeus’ rule.
> I defeat the meaning of the ones after me.
> Pseudonymous Bosch understands me. He wrote about me in his journal :P

Comment: By "any whole symbol" do you mean individual characters or the whole picture?

Comment: I edited the picture. Is this more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the word you seek is

> Anti

You can obtain it by:

> Removing the bottom match of the first symbol (now an A)
>  Rotating the second symbol by 90 degrees to the right (now an N)
>  Putting the match removed from the first symbol onto the top of the first vertical match (now a T)
>  Moving both horizontal matches in the third symbol above and below the last vertical match, both of them perpendicular to the match (now an I)
>  [I am not currently able to produce a visual representation of this, any edit with one is welcome]

As for the riddle:

> Born in during Zeus’ rule.

> Anti comes from Ancient Greek (ἀντ)

> I defeat the meaning of the ones after me.

> Anti defeats whatever comes after it, making it mean the opposite

> Pseudonymous Bosch understands me. He wrote about me in his journal :P

> Pseudonymous Bosch wrote The Anti-Book in 2021

Comment: Great job! You got it correct.